# Trigonometry pre calculus level question

Tags: trigonometry

Here is a trigonometry problem.

> Given
>   $$\frac{\cos(\alpha-3\theta)}{\cos^3(\theta)}=\frac{\sin(\alpha-3\theta)}{\sin^3(\theta)} = m$$
>   Show that 
>   $$m^2+m\cos(\theta) = 2.$$

I tried to convert $\sin^3(x)$ into $\sin(3x)$ and similarly to cosine term, but couldn't get the answer. Please tell how to proceed further and any other way to solve it.

Comment: You should typeset that picture, as the picture is likely to disappear over time.

Comment: I am a beginner and don't know how to do that. It would be good if u will help me. Thanks

Comment: I believe I did so @Kamal, let me know if this is the problem you are asking. For future questions, look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yes this is the one i am looking for. I will not repeat it in future. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I think it's wrong.

Try $\theta=45^{\circ}$ and $\alpha=0^{\circ}$.

We obtain $m=-2$ and $m^2+m\cos\theta=2$ is wrong.

By the way, the first condition gives $$\tan\alpha=\frac{3\sin4\theta}{1+3\cos4\theta}.$$

Comment: Maybe it holds good for a specific value.

Comment: @Kamal I think it's another problem already. By the way, I solved your problem.

Comment: can you please provide a generalized way without value putting.

Comment: Sorry there is a change in question instead of theta it is alpha

Comment: @Kamal It's another problem already. I solved your first problem It's not fair! Open please another topic.

Comment: Yes its a new correct problem. Extremely sorry for the wrong question. Would be nice if you will help me in this one

Comment: @Kamal Open new  topic with your new problem and restore the given.

Comment: I have opened a new topic please refer their. Thanks for the help